# Scrollable div with overflow:hidden in FireFox 3.6.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

On my web site I need to create custom vertical scrollbar. There is div with some content. Div has overflow:hidden (I need this for custom scrollbar).

I have a table lays on this div. At start content size is less then div size.

steps to reproduce:

1. I add new row. After that content size is over size of div.
2. Then I scroll down to the end.
3. Delete newly added row.

After that "table hides under top of div" in FF < 3.6.x.

In other browsers all works fine also in FF > 3.6.x.

To fix this I reassign scrollTop for this div but it causes jumping.

See example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nHuxT/14/

Are any solution to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason you need to run this in FF 3.6? Is other stuff only working in 3.6?

Comment: I have some customers working in FF 3.6.x.

Comment: How are users without mouse wheels supposed to scroll?

Comment: :) on my site I have created custom vertical scrollbar. File with its logic is not small. Thats why I created waxwork on my demo. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment because of my reputation and can't send you any kind of private message, so I have to post it as an answer. I've downloaded FF 3.6.x and checked your demo on jsFiddle - I clicked and looked at it and compared the results with FF5 and IE9 - I didn't notice any differences though. I may not understand the bug you are talking about, but the demo you presented works fine on FF3.6, FF5 and IE9.

Since the demo doesn't have any divs you mentioned, maybe it would be better if you would provide us a demo with divs and everything else that makes the script buggy on FF 3.6?

Comment: I'm talking about <div id="bodyContainer">. It is in my demo.